# Unsuccessful Google Maps API calls in R

Tags: json, r, api, google-maps

I need to extract Geo codes based on location names which I have in a vector in R. I came across this code which calls the Google Maps API with the address given and returns back the coordinates.

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(plyr)

url <- function(address, return.call = "json", sensor = "false") {
root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/"
u <- paste(root, return.call, "?address=", address, "&sensor=", sensor, sep= "")
return(URLencode(u))
}

geoCode <- function(address,verbose=FALSE) {
if(verbose) cat(address,"\n")
u <- url(address)
doc <- getURL(u)
x <- fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE)
if(x$status=="OK") {
  lat <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
  lng <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
  location_type  <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location_type
  formatted_address  <- x$results[[1]]$formatted_address
  return(c(lat, lng, location_type, formatted_address))
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  } else {
  return(c(NA,NA,NA, NA))
 }
}
# address contains around 200 location names
locations  <- ldply(address, function(x) geoCode(x))
```

When I'm running this code, for about half of the records, I'm getting a status other than 'OK' and hence getting the coordinates as NA. However when I make a call again individually, its coming out fine.

I can retrigger the API individually but is there a way this can be done efficiently? A sample of the json [response](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Alberta&sensor=false).

Comment: Have you considered using `geocode()` in the `ggmap` package?

Comment: Don't have much of an idea about ggmap package. Will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid Google Maps API key, you can use my package [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway), and in particular the `google_geocode()` function

For example

```
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

addresses <- c("The White House, Washington DC, USA", 
               "MCG, Melbourne, Australia",
               "Buckingham Palace, UK")

lst <- lapply(addresses, function(x){
  google_geocode(x, key = key) ## use simplify = F for JSON
})


lst[[1]]$results$formatted_address
# [1] "The White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500, USA"

lst[[2]]$results$formatted_address
# [1] "Jolimont Station, Wellington Cres, East Melbourne VIC 3002, Australia"

lst[[3]]$results$formatted_address
# [1] "Buckingham Palace, London SW1A 1AA, UK"
```